# DialogFragment при повороте экрана

Tags: android

Один `DialogFragment` на нажатие кнопки вызывает другой `DialogFragment`(Первый не закрывается). т.е. в стеке у нас Frag1 -> Frag2. При повороте экрана Происходит странная вещь, перед лицом появляется Frag1, а за ним видно Frag2. Т.е. Frag2 -> Frag1. Как сделать наоборот? Есть какие-нибудь решения?

Первый диалог:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_category_dialog, container, false);

    EditText moneyET = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.newCategory_moneyET);
    EditText categoryET = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.newCategory_categoryET);
    Button colorBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.newCategory_colorBtn);
    Button negativeBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.newCategory_negativeBtn);
    Button positiveBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.newCategory_positiveBtn);

    DialogListener listener = new DialogListener(getFragmentManager(), getDialog(), moneyET, categoryET);

    colorBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
    negativeBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
    positiveBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);

    return view;
}
```

Второй диалог:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_picker_dialog, null);

    ColorPickerView colorPickerView = (ColorPickerView) view.findViewById(R.id.color_picker_view);
    Button positiveBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.color_positiveBtn);
    Button negativeBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.color_negativeBtn);

    DialogListener listener = new DialogListener(getDialog());

    colorPickerView.addOnColorSelectedListener(listener);
    positiveBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
    negativeBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
    return view;
}
```

Класс-слушатель:

```
switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.newCategory_negativeBtn:
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.newCategory_positiveBtn:
                break;
            case R.id.newCategory_colorBtn:
                ColorPickerDialog colorDialog = new ColorPickerDialog();
                colorDialog.show(fragmentManager, "colorPickerDialog");
                break;
            // для диалога выбора цвета
            case R.id.color_positiveBtn:
                break;
            case R.id.color_negativeBtn:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Скинули вы бы сюда код. Что-то я не думаю что они у вас в одном стеке. И вообще использование 2-ух DialogFragment таким образом не очень хорошая идея. Я бы сделал Frag1 обычным фрагментом, который вызывает Frag2, который уже DialogFragment.

Comment: @CookieMnstr Обновил. суть в том, что в первом диалоге надо нажать на кубик, появляется новое диалоговое окно с палитрой, там выбираем цвет, нажимаем "ОК" диалог палитры закрывается и кубик в первом диалоге должен окраситься в нужный цвет. На словах всё легко, а на деле понятия не имею как всё это сделать. И еще, "стек" это я образно сказал, я честно сказать, понятие не имею как они себя ведут, но раз это DialogFRAGMENT, то наверняка они в стеке.

Comment: может попробовать запретить перерисовку активности при повороте экрана? в манифесте на уровне application добавьте android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: @CookieMnstr очень ограничивает, т.к. все приложение построено вокруг одного активити.